# In ruby, for a 2d array, how can I remove lines that match another line apart from one value?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Given an array like the following:

```
array = [[1, "a", 34], [1, "a", 72], [1, "b", 82],
         [2, "a", 72], [2, "b", 34], [2, "b", 32],
         [3, "a", 72], [3, "b", 82], [3, "b", 34],
         [4, "a", 93], [4, "b", 15]]
```

I would like to know how, using ruby, I could  remove all of the lines that match all values in another line apart from the first value which has to be equal to `n-1`.
So that would mean that `[1, "a", 72]` is deleted since there is a line with `[2, "a", 72]` which would also be deleted since `[3, "a", 72]` is present.
`[2, "b", 34]` would also be deleted since there is `[3, "b", 34]`

The script would therefore return the following array:

```
array = [[1, "a", 34], [1, "b", 82],
         [2, "b", 32],
         [3, "a", 72], [3, "b", 82], [3, "b", 34],
         [4, "a", 93], [4, "b", 15]]
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution has a time-complexity of O(n).

**Code**

```
def prune(arr)
  keepers_idx =
    arr.each_with_index.
        with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}) do |((n,*rest),i),h|
          h[rest].pop if h.key?(rest) && n == arr[h[rest].last].first + 1
          h[rest] << i
        end
  arr.values_at *(arr.size.times.to_a & keepers_idx.values.flatten)
end
```

**Example**

I've added the element `[5, "b", 34]` to the end of the array given in the question:

```
array = [
  [1, "a", 34], [1, "a", 72], [1, "b", 82],
  [2, "a", 72], [2, "b", 34], [2, "b", 32],
  [3, "a", 72], [3, "b", 82], [3, "b", 34],
  [4, "a", 93], [4, "b", 15], [5, "b", 34]
]

prune(array) 
  #=> [[1, "a", 34], [1, "b", 82], [2, "b", 32], [3, "a", 72], [3, "b", 82],
  #    [3, "b", 34], [4, "a", 93], [4, "b", 15], [5, "b", 34]]
```

**Explanation**

`prune` returns the reduced array but does not modify its argument, `array`. If `array` is to be replaced write

```
array = prune(array)
```

or change the last line of the method to:

```
array.replace(array.values_at *keepers_idx.values.flatten(1).sort)
```

depending on requirements.

The values in `keepers_idx` are the indices of the elements of `array` that are to be retained whose last 2 elements are given by the corresponding keys. For example, the arrays ending `["b", 82]` to be retained are at indices `2` and `7`. Note also that when `arr = array`,

```
keepers_idx 
  #=> {["a", 34]=>[0], ["a", 72]=>[6], ["b", 82]=>[2, 7], ["b", 34]=>[8, 11],
  #    ["b", 32]=>[5], ["a", 93]=>[9], ["b", 15]=>[10]}
```

and

```
arr.size.times.to_a & keepers_idx.values.flatten
  #=> [0, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

The empty hash created by `h = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}` has the property that if `h` does not have a key `k`, say `k = ['a', 34]`, then

```
h[k] #=> []
```

so we can write

```
h[k] << 0
  #=> [0]
```

Use of the *default proc* is equivalent to:

```
h[k] = [] unless h.key?(k)
h[k] << 0
```

**Step-by-step**

Now lets step through the code for the example array.

```
arr = array
enum = arr.each_with_index.with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]})
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [[1, "a", 34], [1, "a", 72],
  #     [1, "b", 82],...[5, "b", 34]]:each_with_index>:with_object({})>
```

The first value is generated by the enumerator (see [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next)), passed to the block and the block variables are assigned values by a process known as [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition):

```
((n,*rest),i),h = enum.next
     #=> [[[1, "a", 34], 0], {}] 
n    #=> 1 
rest #=> ["a", 34] 
i    #=> 0 
h    #=> {}
```

We now perform the block calculation.

```
h.key?(rest)
  #=> {}.key(["a", 34]) => false
```

so we do not perform `h[rest].pop`. Continuing,

```
h[rest] << i 
  #=> h[["a", 34]] << 0 => [0] 
h #=> {["a", 34]=>[0]}
```

The next element is generated by `enum`, passed to the block, the block variables are assigned values and the block calculation is performed.

```
((n,*rest),i),h = enum.next
  #=> [[[1, "a", 72], 1], {["a", 34]=>[0]}] 
n    #=> 1 
rest #=> ["a", 72] 
i    #=> 1 
h    #=> {["a", 34]=>[0]} 

h.key?(rest)
  #=> {}.key(["a", 72]) => false => *no* h[rest].pop
h[rest] << i 
  #=> h[["a", 72]] << 1 => [1] 
h #=> {["a", 34]=>[0], ["a", 72]=>[1]}
```

After one more similar step,

```
h=> {["a", 34]=>[0], ["a", 72]=>[1], ["b", 82]=>[2]}
```

Now things are about to change.

```
((n,*rest),i),h = enum.next
  #=> [[[2, "a", 72], 3], {["a", 34]=>[0], ["a", 72]=>[1], ["b", 82]=>[2]}]
n    #=> 2 
rest #=> ["a", 72] 
i    #=> 3 
h    #=> {["a", 34]=>[0], ["a", 72]=>[1], ["b", 82]=>[2]}  

h.key?(rest)
  #=> h.key?(["a", 72]) => true
n == arr[h[rest].last].first + 1
  #=> 2 == arr[h[["a", 72]].last].first + 1
  #=> 2 == arr[[1].last].first + 1
  #=> 2 == arr[1].first + 1
  #=> 2 == [1, "a", 72].first + 1 => true
```

so we execute

```
h[rest].pop     
  #=> h[["a", 72]].pop => 1
h #=> {["a", 34]=>[0], ["a", 72]=>[], ["b", 82]=>[2]}
```

Continuing,

```
h[rest] << i
  #=> h[["a", 72]] << 3 => [3] 
h #=> {["a", 34]=>[0], ["a", 72]=>[3], ["b", 82]=>[2]}
```

The remaining calculations to obtain `keepers_idx` are similar, producing:

```
keepers_idx
  #=> {["a", 34]=>[0], ["a", 72]=>[6], ["b", 82]=>[2, 7], ["b", 34]=>[8, 11],
  #    ["b", 32]=>[5], ["a", 93]=>[9], ["b", 15]=>[10]}
```

Lastly,

```
  arr.values_at *(0..arr.size-1).to_a & keepers_idx.values.flatten

a = keepers_idx.values
  #=> [[0], [6], [2, 7], [8, 11], [5], [9], [10]] 
b = a.flatten
  #=> [0, 6, 2, 7, 8, 11, 5, 9, 10] 
c = arr.size.times.to_a
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11] 
d = c & b
  #=> [0, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

arr.values_at *d
  #=> arr.values_at(0, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11) 
  #=> [[1, "a", 34], [1, "b", 82], [2, "b", 32], [3, "a", 72], [3, "b", 82],
  #=>  [3, "b", 34], [4, "a", 93], [4, "b", 15], [5, "b", 34]]
```

In computing `c & b`, the doc [Array#&](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-26) guarantees that "The order is preserved from the original array [`c`].".

**Processing a file**

Evidently, the elements of `array` are contained in a large file. Let's assume the file has the following format for the array `array` given above.

```
s = array.map { |a| a.map(&:to_s).join(",") }.join("\n")
puts s
1,a,34
1,a,72
1,b,82
2,a,72
2,b,34
2,b,32
3,a,72
3,b,82
3,b,34
4,a,93
4,b,15
5,b,34
```

`s` could have an ending newline (it doesn't matter). Let's write that to file.

```
FName = 'temp'
File.write(FName, s)
  #=> 83
```

Check it:

```
s == File.read(FName)
  #=> true
```

The method could be modified as follows. Two passes are made through the file, reading line-by-line.

The first pass constructs the hash `keepers`. This hash is similar to `keepers_idx`, above, but the values are modified. The values of `keeper_idx` are arrays of indices. The values of `keepers` are arrays of two-element arrays of the form `[i,n]`, where `i` is the index of the line in the file and `n` is the first integer obtained from that line. Consider, for example, the line `"1,b,82"` at index `2`. The array `[2,1]` would then be appended to the value (array) of the key `["b",82]`, the value having been initialised to an empty array.

The second pass through the file extracts the lines at indices given by `keepers`, held in the sorted array `lines_to_keep`. I've returned an array of the extracted lines, converted to three-element arrays. (See the comment at then end if this is not permitted due to insufficient memory.)

```
def prune(fname)
  keepers =
    File.foreach(fname).
         with_index.
         with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}) do |(line,i),h|
           n, *rest = convert(line)
           h[rest].pop if h.key?(rest) && n == h[rest].last.last + 1
           h[rest] << [i,n]
         end
  keepers = keepers.values.flatten(1).map(&:first)
  keepers = (0..keepers.max).to_a & keepers
  next_line = keepers.shift
  File.foreach(fname).
       with_index.
       with_object([]) do |(line,i),a|
         if i == next_line
           a << convert(line)
           next_line = keepers.shift
           break a if keepers.nil?
         end
       end
end

def convert(line)
  a,b,c = line.chomp.split(',')
  [a.to_i, b, c.to_i]
end
```

```
prune(FName)
  #=> [[1, "a", 34], [1, "b", 82], [2, "b", 32], [3, "a", 72], [3, "b", 82],
       [3, "b", 34], [4, "a", 93], [4, "b", 15], [5, "b", 34]]
```

Notes:

- It may be faster to replace the line

```
keepers = (0..keepers.max).to_a & keepers
```

with

```
keepers.sort!
```

- Depending on the file format, it may of course be necessary to modify `convert`. At present:

```
convert "1,a,34"
  #=> [1, "a", 34]
```

- If the array returned by `prune` is too large to hold in memory, one could replace the line `a << convert(line)` with one that writes `line` to a file previously-opened for writing.
- If the hash `keepers` is itself too large to hold in memory, it would have to be written to and read from a database table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not familiar with time-complexity, does a time-complexity of O(n) mean that it will run faster or slower than the other proposed answer?

Comment: @Hildobby This will run faster than my answer: my answer is `O(n^2)` worst-case whereas this is `O(n)`.

Comment: Hildobby, see [this Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) for an explanation of time complexity.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland ! This works great and is indeed much faster than the other proposed solution. However, for very large files, I get the following error ```stack level too deep (SystemStackError)``` on this line: ```arr.values_at *(arr.size.times.to_a & keepers_idx.values.flatten)```, how can I solve this?

Comment: How large are the files that cause the error? Also, among all elements `[a,b,c]` in a problem file, do you have any idea of the number of unique arrays `[b,c]` (which are the keys in my hash)?

Comment: The file in question contains about 15 500 000 lines (about 450 MB) and out of those, about 5% or so are unique while the rest should get removed.

Comment: @CarySwoveland do you know how I could get the result for those larger files?

Comment: I've added some code and discussion at the end to process a file. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 4):

I would do it like this:

```
array.delete_if do |item|
  a, b, c = item
  array.include? [a + 1, b, c]
end
```

This iterates through the array and, for each item:

1. Destructures the array into three separate variables, `a`, `b` and `c`. (You should probably give these more descriptive names when you use this in your own code!)
2. Reconstructs the array with `a` incremented, and checks if this new array is present in `array`.
3. If so, delete this item.

Please note that this mutates `array` directly rather than returning an altered copy.

Comment: You can assign to a,b and c directly in the block arguments: `array.delete_if{|a,b,c| array.include?([a+1,b,c]) }`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it's exactly what I was looking for! Is there a reason why defined ```item``` before defining ```a,b,c```? Wouldn't it be simpler to remove the second line and define ```a,b,c```in the block arguments?

Comment: @Dobby You're welcome! It probably would be easier to do exactly that, I'd just forgotten about that feature.